# Change of orbit with radial impulse

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, rocket-science, satellites

This probably is  dumb question, but it has been giving me issues for days.
I was thinking about a point of mass $m$ in a circular orbit around a planet. The question is: giving a radial impulse, what is the change in the shape of the orbit? Will it change in another circular orbit? Or maybe will undergo a spiral motion?

Comment: The question is not that dumb. Radial impulse is the least efficient in changing in-plane orbit parameters (prograde or retrograde impulses are the most efficient). If you apply a large enough impulse towards the center of the planet, though, you may be able to enter the atmosphere and experience constantly increasing drag which will slow you down and put you into a re-entry trajectory. In vacuum, orbits are assumed to be Keplerian conic sections (ellipses, parabolic and hyperbolic). Circular orbit is just a special case of an ellipse.

Comment: And applying the impulse radially in the direction outward, how would it influence the orbit? Anyway thanks for the reply

Comment: Please bear in mind that we're talking about short (instantaneous) propulsive maneuvers. After an outward impulse done in any place of a circular orbit the orbit becomes elliptical.

Comment: Recommended books on astrodynamics: Battin, Vallado, Bate/Mueller/White.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you are in a circular orbit around the Earth. You are always at the same altitude, your path's curvature exactly follows that of the Earth's surface. You are basically [Newton's cannonball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_cannonball).

All of a sudden, you get a huge kick in the outward radial direction.

You will experience an instantaneous change of velocity, both in magnitude (greater speed) and direction (pointed not just forward, but also outward).

Due to conservation of energy and conservation of angular momentum, your path around the Earth will still be periodic in an inertial reference frame. That is, some time in the near future, you will find yourself at the exact same spot in space, with the exact same velocity.

But what's interesting is what wil happen in the meantime.

Because your velocity is now *not* parallel to the Earth's surface but has an outward component as well, your altitude will start increasing. This means that you will exchange kinetic energy for potential energy; your altitude will increase, at the expense of your speed. At some point, the outward component of your velocity will have decreased all the way to zero, so that you have reached your maximum possible altitude.

At this point, the tangential component of your velocity will *also* have decreased to a value that is *too low* to allow you to stay at your current altitude; it is very much like you are being pushed over the top of a hill. Slowly but surely, you will start falling back to the Earth, decreasing your altitude while gaining speed. Both your radial and tangential speeds will increase, but the increased tangential speed implies also an increased centripetal acceleration with respect to the center of the Earth. This will cause your inward-pointed radial speed to grow *initially*, but gradually decrease again until it has reached zero at the point where you have reached your greatest speed and lowest altitude.

Imagine the shape of the whole path you have just traveled. Does your imagination agree with the actual simulation of this scenario shown below?

[image]
[image]

In summary: you will find yourself in an *elliptical* orbit.

The question that usually pops up in this context is what will happen with *constant* radial accelerations; not just sudden bursts at a single point in the orbit, but a constant outward-pointed force. Intuitively, this is what most people would do when they would want to steer their space-ships away from the Earth. However, this is what would happen in that case:

[image]

***CRASH!***

This is because the radial force *does not bring about any changes to the angular momentum*. It does not increase the total energy of the orbit, just its in-plane offset. The net effect of the constant radial force is equal to a local change in the attractive gravitational force. And since gravity is a [conservative force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field), there can be no net gain in energy.

In order to really get away from the Earth, you'd have to point that same amount of force *tangentially* to the orbit (or more generally, in the orbital plane and parallel to the local horizontal), in order for it to bring about the maximum possible change to the angular momentum. This is what that would look like:

[image]

Comment: I found your answer really usefull, and I think I've almost completely understood this issue. There is just one little question about something you said. "At this point, the tangential component of your velocity will also have decreased". Now, shouldn't only the radial component of velocity decrease, because fo the central froce of gravity ?

Comment: @Drogor: Think of a car driving really fast on a horizontal road. Let's say there is no air drag, road resistance, etc. The driver pushes the clutch, so there is no thrust from the engine anymore. At that same moment, the road starts to incline, and the car starts to climb up the hill ahead. When the car reaches the top of the hill, its will have lost a lot of speed. Why do you think this happens, if the force of gravity is only down, while the velocity was only forward in the beginning?

Comment: Well, when the car starts climbing the hill, there will be a component of the force relevant for letting the car to slow down. In the planet problem, I think that the force is only directed radially, so there is no component on the tangential direction.

Comment: But, I'm thinking... after the impulse is applied, the velocity of the planet is not directed anymore in the tangential direction, so that in general the speed will decrease, untill velocity becomes again only tangential. Is that right?

Comment: @Drogor: Hmmm...not following you. In the car problem, how does the purely vertical gravity decrease both components of  the partially vertical, partially horizontal velocity of the car? As for your second comment; yes, that is roughly right, however, the key thing to realize is that *both* the tangential and radial components will decrease due to the increase in altitude.

Comment: @Drogor: I think the following explanation will help. Imagine a spacecraft at some position above the ground. It has a velocity, 1 part "up" and 1 part "to the right". From an observer in an inertial reference frame, the gravitational acceleration is initially 1 part straight down. An infinitesimal amount of time later, the downward acceleration will have decreased the upward component of the velocity, and have left the horizontal component intact. However, the acceleration vector has now also rotated slightly in the clockwise direction, do the the changed position of the spacecraft.

Comment: @Drogor: during the next infinitesimal amount of time, the component of the velocity *that is currently vertical* will be decreased by the gravitational acceleration. It is this continually changing direction of the acceleration that causes the *entire* speed to decrease, not just the purely radial part. As seen "from the current time step", that has a different definition of "radial" and "tangential", the acceleration "from the previous time step" has induced changes in both tangential and radial directions. Yes, polar coordinates are treacherous in many ways.

Comment: Oh I got it, I think. Due to this rotation, the horizontal component of the velocity is decreased. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis.  Nice explanation.  But a terminology question.  What is an outward tangential thrust?  That sounds like an oxymoron.

Answer (score 2):

> Will it change in another circular orbit?

The radial velocity of a circular orbit is zero.  Since the radial impulse imparts a radial velocity to the point mass, the new orbit cannot be a circular one.

> Or maybe will undergo a spiral motion ?

No, assuming two ideal point masses in the Newtonian context and no drag, the new orbit must be a conic section as Deer Hunter points out in a comment.

Comment: I think I've undestood. Now my doubt is: how can I study the orbit ? I mean, how would this impulse change the effective potential ? For every orbit I've tried to study untill this moment I had to use this effective potential, but it considers the angular moment. A radial impulse would modify it anyway?