# Changing orbits by an impulse

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, rocket-science, satellites

I have read several stack exchange posts on this, and [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70357/2451) was certainly quite close to my query, but i am still not getting it entirely. I cannot motivate why providing an impulse tangent to an orbit will cause the planet/satellite to go into a CIRCULAR orbit of greater radius (Hohmann transfer) whereas a radial impulse will cause it to go into an elliptical orbit. Mathematically, what is the reason for the two different results? Why can a radial impulse not cause deflection into an orbit of greater radius (okay i think this one is because angular momentum would then not be conserved) and why can a tangential impulse not just lead to a stable elliptical orbit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hohmann Transfer takes a satellite from one circular orbit to another via an elliptical orbit.

For a circular orbit the magnitude of velocity is constant, and its direction is always perpendicular to the radius. For an elliptical orbit the magnitude of velocity varies, and its direction is perpendicular to the radius at only 2 points in the orbit : viz. at the ends of the major axis. At the further of these points from the attracting focus (the apogee) the speed is too slow for a circular orbit at that radius; at the closer point (the perigee) the speed is too fast.

The idea of the Hohmann Transfer is to increase or decrease the satellite's speed instantaneously at one of these 2 points to match the speed required for a circular orbit of that radius. So when the satellite is at its furthest from the focus (the apogee) a boost in speed can put it into a circular orbit with the maximum radius of the elliptical orbit, while at the closest point (the perigee) a reduction in speed can put it into a circular orbit with minimum radius of the ellipse.
[image]

The increase/decrease in speed has to be calculated precisely in order get a circular orbit, otherwise another elliptical orbit with a different eccentricity will result.

The angular momentum of the satellite is not conserved because matter is ejected from it to create the impulse. This ejecta has angular momentum, and the total angular momentum is conserved.

If the satellite is already in a circular orbit any radial impulse will give it a new velocity which is not perpendicular to the radius vector. So the new orbit will not be circular; it will be elliptical. A tangential impulse reverses the above manoeuvre, resulting in an elliptical orbit.

A Hohmann Transfer (impulse at apogee/perigee) is not the only possibility for getting between elliptical and circular orbits. At other points around the ellipse an impulse of suitable magnitude and direction (partly tangential, partly radial) will transfer the satallite to a circular orbit. Hohmann Transfers are preferred because they are the most fuel-efficient.

Answer (score 6):

> I cannot motivate why providing an impulse tangent to an orbit will cause the planet/satellite to go into a CIRCULAR orbit of greater radius (Hohmann transfer) whereas a radial impulse will cause it to go into an elliptical orbit.

You have a misunderstanding of what a Hohmann transfer is.

A Hohmann transfer involves two tangential impulsive maneuvers. The first maneuver transfers an object from a circular orbit to an elliptical orbit. The second maneuver half an orbit later transfers the object from that elliptical transfer orbit to a circular orbit with a different radius than the original circular orbit.

If that second impulsive maneuver does not occur, the object will continue to orbit in that elliptical transfer orbit.