# Method adapted by ISRO

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, propulsion, space-mission, nasa

Why does the ISRO change orbits of a satellite in many steps?

I've seen them do this in the **MANGALYAAN** as well as **CHANDRAYAAN II** missions.

From what I understand, changing the orbit of the satellite requires you to increase the total energy of the Earth-satellite system. This can be done by changing the velocity of the satellite. This alone must change the length of the semi-major axis of the ellipse and therefore the trajectory.

I also understand why it's done at the perigee of the trajectory.

What I don't understand is :
**"Why change the orbit in multiple steps? Why not all at once?"**

(In the movie **MISSION MANGAL**, they explain that it's done to save fuel but I don't see how it's going to save us any fuel. According to the movie, this method was invented by the **ISRO** to help save fuel which means **NASA**, or other properly funded organisations did not use this method as they had big enough rockets that carry more fuel)

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: ISRO stands for Indian Space Research Organisation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing orbits by an impulse](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/384480)