# Change of orbit with tangential impulse

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, rocket-science, satellites

I see a similar question:  [Change of orbit with a radial impulse.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70357/)  The answer to that question seems fine to me.  In the answer, mention is made of *this* similar question, but it is not fully treated.

So, suppose a satellite is in a perfectly circular orbit.  If you impart a brief forward impulse (in the direction of the orbit), what now happens to the orbit?  (And what about a backward impulse?)

Comment: Have you seen this one? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/480904/

Comment: @Gert, I'm familiar with the qualitative aspects of adding velocity to a circular orbit.  However, I have never seen an equation for calculating the shape of the resulting elliptical orbit.  Does such an equation exist?

Comment: @DavidWhite: I believe it would be very complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480904/trajectory-of-a-satellite-whose-velocity-is-less-than-circular-orbital-velocity). Consider a satellite whose speed changes as $\vec {v}=k\vec {v}$ at some point of the trajectory. Figure 1 shows the trajectory before the speed has changed  (blue) and after (orange). We see an elliptical trajectory that is getting farther from the central body at $k>1$ ant it is getting closer to the central body with decreasing $k$. When $k\ge \sqrt {2}$, the satellite leaves the central body.
[image: fig1]

Comment: Very nice.  The diagrams you gave answer exactly what I was wondering, and additional cases as well.  I guess it would be irresponsible to just believe you.  After some search, I found what is called the vis-viva equation.  Is that what you used, or did you derive these in some other way?

Comment: @MarkGoldfain This is the result of numerical simulation.

Comment: Okay, so you simulate a central gravitational pull or acceleration and different initial velocities.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MarkGoldfain You're welcome. I solved the problem as it is. At the beginning, the satellite moves in a circular orbit, then the satellite speed suddenly changes according to the law $\vec {v_1}=k\vec {v_0}$. As a result, the satellite moves to an elliptical orbit.